# Does WSGI override `Content-Length` header?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, wsgi

HTTP `HEAD` requests should contain the `Content-Length` header as if they were `GET` requests. But if I set a `Content-Length` header it gets overridden by the WSGI environment ([discussion related to mod_wsgi](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/10/wsgi-issues-with-http-head-requests.html)).

Take a look at the following example:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', '77')]
    start_response(status, headers)
    return []

httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
print("Serving on port 8000...")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

... and then calling it with `curl`:

```
$ curl -X HEAD http://localhost:8000/ -i
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 16:02:27 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0                         <-- should be 77
```

How can I tell the WSGI environment not to override the content length value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such configuration setting. You have to override or modify `wsgiref/handlers.py`, like this:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from wsgiref.simple_server import ServerHandler
def finish_content(self):
    """Ensure headers and content have both been sent"""
    if not self.headers_sent:
        if (self.environ.get('REQUEST_METHOD', '') != 'HEAD' or
            'Content-Length' not in self.headers):
            self.headers['Content-Length'] = 0
        self.send_headers()
ServerHandler.finish_content = finish_content
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', '77')]
    start_response(status, headers)
    return []
httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
print("Serving on port 8000...")
httpd.serve_forever()
```